# Why resizing image lead to increase in channels?

Tags: python, image, resize, grayscale, channel

I have grayscale images of different dimensions so I need to convert them to same dimension (say, 28*28) for my experiments. I tried to do it using different methods and I was able to do it but I observed that resizing of image lead to increase in number of channels. I am new to python and image processing so please help.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('6.tif')
image = image.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save('6.png', 'PNG', quality=100)
```

And then following code shows different dimensions:

```
import imageio

image_data = imageio.imread("6.tif").astype(float)
print(image_data.shape)

image_data = imageio.imread("6.png").astype(float)
print(image_data.shape)
```

and result is:

```
(65, 74)
(28, 28, 4)
```

I don't need the last dimension. How is this coming? I get the similar results even with "from resizeimage import resizeimage".

Comment: Please share your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code...

---

If you are expecting a greyscale image, make sure that is what you get. So, change this:

```
image = Image.open('6.tif')
```

to:

```
image = Image.open('6.tif').convert('L')
```

---

When you resize an image, you need to use one of the correct resampling methods:

- PIL.Image.NEAREST
- PIL.Image.BOX
- PIL.Image.BILINEAR
- PIL.Image.HAMMING
- PIL.Image.BICUBIC
- PIL.Image.LANCZOS

So, you need to replace the `ANTI_ALIAS` with something from the above list on this line:

```
image = image.resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

---

When you save as PNG, it is **always** loss-less. The quality factor does not work the same as for JPEG images, so you should omit it unless you have a good understanding of how it affects the PNG encoder.

---

If you make these changes, specifically the first, I think your problem will go away. Bear in mind though that the PNG encoder *may* take an RGB image and save it as a palletised image, or it may take a greyscale image and encode it as RGB, or RGB alpha.

Comment: Thank you Mark! Thank you for the solution and the prompt response. You're right first part fixes the issue, i.e., by adding .convert('L'). I tried this earlier but wrongly as .convert("LA").

Comment: Cool - glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Even if I do this I get 4 channels: img = Image.open(path_to_img); img = img.resize((512, 512)).